# code ELIFECYCLE npm local pacakges not working

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

```
╰─ npm run dev

> nextjspractise@0.1.0 dev /home/auura/D:drive/React/nextjspractise
> next dev

sh: 1: next: not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! nextjspractise@0.1.0 dev: `next dev`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the nextjspractise@0.1.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/auura/.npm/_logs/2020-04-01T06_32_26_968Z-debug.log
```

package.json file

```
{
  "name": "nextjspractise",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "next": "9.3.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1"
  }
}
```

After installing nextjs packages and scripts when I tried using npm run dev there my local packages were not working even package.json contains all packages same with node_modules then also there is a error for package not found

If I install next react react-dom packages globally then npm run dev command executes fine but local packages are not working

local packages not working 
operating system : Ubuntu 18.04.4

Answer (score 0):

Change your scripts in `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "nextjspractise",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm dev",
    "build": "npm build",
    "start": "npm start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "next": "9.3.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1"
  }
}
```

**npm** is the de-facto standard to run your node applications. (**yarn** is also an alternate)

Answer (score -1):

Just doing `npm i` or `npm install` and then running the command `npm run dev` ( for NextJS ) worked fime for me :)